# How to setup HP printer/scanner on ubuntu 16.04?

Tags: 16.04, printing

The printer/scanner worked when i was on the last LTS just fine (almost), but now after i've upgraded it tells me that it is unable to connect to the device.

I have attempted to do what [HPPrinterInstallation](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/HPPrinterInstallation) says and i got the following:

```
$ gksudo hp-setup

HP Linux Imaging and Printing System (ver. 3.16.3)
Printer/Fax Setup Utility ver. 9.0

Copyright (c) 2001-15 HP Development Company, LP
This software comes with ABSOLUTELY NO WARRANTY.
This is free software, and you are welcome to distribute it
under certain conditions. See COPYING file for more details.

warning: Qt/PyQt 4 initialization failed.
error: hp-setup requires GUI support (try running with --qt3). Also, try using interactive (-i) mode.
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok, i have found an answer for my question. So i'm posting it here, in hopes that it will be useful for another person:

For whatever bizaar reason the graphical interface of `hp-setup` is busted. So one needs to start:

sudo hp-setup -i

The `-i` key is essential, because without it the setup doesn't proceed either. At this time i still haven't gotten the test page out, but the scanner is working properly, which is what i was needing originally.

Comment: You might just need the `hplip-gui` package which brings in the requirements for said busted gui.